# issue of string index out of range

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

When I try to implement my code an error appears, but when I use a debugger to see where the code's stuck there is no index out of range. I must miss something but I don't know what.

```
message = "WEATHERREPORTWINDYTODAY"
number1 = 7

def Encode(letter, number):
    shift = 0
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    liste_decode = []
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        number_index_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter[i]) + shift + number
        shift += 1
        if number_index_alphabet <= len(alphabet):
            liste_decode.append(alphabet[number_index_alphabet])
        else:
            number_index_alphabet -= 26
            liste_decode.append(alphabet[number_index_alphabet])

    return liste_decode
print(Encode(message, number1))
```

Comment: can you give the exact error message/traceback ?

Comment: number_index_alphabet == 26 at some point. The index range for *alphabet* is 0-25 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Number_index_alphabet == 26 at some point. The index range for alphabet is 0-25 inclusive. You will have also problem with that line:

```
number_index_alphabet -= 26
```

Working code:

```
if number_index_alphabet < len(alphabet):
    liste_decode.append(alphabet[number_index_alphabet])
else:
    number_index_alphabet = number_index_alphabet % 26
    liste_decode.append(alphabet[number_index_alphabet])
```

Answer (score 0):

I see here two possible mistakes

1. `if number_index_alphabet <= len(alphabet):` should be `if number_index_alphabet < len(alphabet):`
2. not sure what you are expecting from this `number_index_alphabet -= 26`

I assume that your function should look like this

```
def Encode(letter, number):
    shift = 0
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    liste_decode = []
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        number_index_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter[i]) + shift + number 
        shift += 1
        liste_decode.append(alphabet[number_index_alphabet % 26])

    return liste_decode
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works perfectly ! Can you explain me, what is the reflect behind, alphabet[number_index_alphabet % 26]) ?

Comment: It is called *Modulo operator*. It finds ***remainder*** after the division of one number by another. For example `5 % 26 = 5` and `31 % 26 = 5`. Hope you got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why out of range is that you incremented `shift` and in one step of the loop `number_index_alphabet` will be `53`, even if in the else statement you minus 26, you get 27, which is out of range.

And in the if statement `number_index_alphabet <= len(alphabet)` will also probably incur out of range error, should be `number_index_alphabet < len(alphabet)`.

I guess you want to encode the sentence with a shift in the alphabet. changed a little bit, hope it helps.

```
message = "WEATHERREPORTWINDYTODAY"
number1 = 7

def Encode(letter, number):
    shift = number
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    str_encode = str()
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        number_index_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter[i]) + shift
        
        if number_index_alphabet >= len(alphabet):
            number_index_alphabet %= len(alphabet)

        str_encode += alphabet[number_index_alphabet]
            
    return str_encode

print(Encode(message, number1))
```

output: `DLHAOLYYLWVYADPUKFAVKHF`